# how do i remove the matched character from a string?

Tags: php

here is my code

```
$a = "Hey there, how do i remove all, the comma from this string,";
$a = str_replace($a,',','';)
echo $a;
```

i want to remove all the commas available in the string, how do i do it?

Comment: What's the problem with str_replace?

Comment: @fabrik arguments were inverted ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$a = str_replace(",", "", $a);
```

Comment: lol, what a stupid mistake i was engaged in.. thank you for correction :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = "Hey there, how do i remove all, the comma from this string,";
$a = str_replace(',','',$a);
echo $a;
```

Misplaced semi-colon and wrong function arguments.